# Symfony 2.4 How to load an external class?

Tags: php, symfony, psr-0

I want to add an external lib into my symfony 2 project. I use the 2.4 version. I have read many "how to" but all solution doesn't work with this version.

Do you tell me how I can do to add my class in my project ?

My class Html2Pdf:

```
<?php    
class Html2Pdf
{   
   // Code ...
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call it in a class using `\Html2Pdf` as you can with any none namespaced class.

**Update**:

As you are using Symfony and Composer the classes and namespace will already mapped so you simply need to include it using the `\Html2Pdf` namespace. The `\` is to signify that it is a namespace based at the root level rather than a relative namespace (in the same folder).

If you were not using composer or something with an autoloader then you would need to include the file somewhere in your stack (this can be in the current file or some kind of parent file that serves this one) using `include_once('**path to file**/Html2Pdf.php')`. You would then use it in the same way as you would when using Symfony/Composer with the `\`.

Comment: Please explain how you include the file before using the class.

Comment: If you have downloaded the package using composer then it will be mapped automatically through the autoloader. Other wise you would probably need to include the file as you would do usually, `include_once("blah\blah\Html2Pdt.php")`. I may have written that wrong because I can't remember that last like I `included` a file (clearly too long in frameworks).

Comment: Ok, I suggest you to add this explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know anything about **services**?

If you want to use that YoutubeDownloader class in controllers, you have to define it as a service so you can call anywhere you want.

Open your services.yml in;

> YourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml

```
parameters:
    youtubeDownload: YourBundle/YourPathToClass

services:
    bundlename.controllername.controller:
        class:     "%youtubeDownload%"
```

More information:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html

Comment: Html2Pdf is an external class... Not a bundle ... ?

Comment: Where did you put that file?

Comment: in /vendor/dimitri/Html2Pdf/Html2Pdf.php

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
include_once $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../path/to/Html2Pdt.php';

$aHtml2Pdt = new \Html2Pdt();
```

I think this is what @Qoop is trying to say to.

I hope it helps.